# How do I return to the main thread from a CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, minecraft, bukkit, completable-future

I need to return to the main thread from a `CompletableFuture<Void>`.

I have a web of `CompletableFuture`'s which run async to process data received and inserted into an SQL database. Once all that is complete however, I want to return to the main thread and execute a function, I have found no reasonable way of doing this.

Calling `join()` or `get()` only blocks the thread that the `CompletableFuture` is running in... I dont want to have to continuously poll `isDone()` either.

I have tried to use `whenComplete()`, but it still doesn't seem to work as expected...

```
public static void updatePermIconCache() {
    Logger.debug("thread1: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    hubDatabase.getLobbies().thenAccept(s -> {
        for (String lobby : s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
                final int x = i;
                hubDatabase.isInPermTable(lobby, i).thenAccept(b -> {
                    if (!b) return;
                    hubDatabase.cachePermToJoinTable(lobby, x);
                });
            }
        }
    }).whenComplete((v, t) -> registerPanels());
}
```

I want my `registerPanels()` function to be the called in the main thread, but considering even the function `updatePermIconCache()` is called async, along with other functions that determine whether this function gets called or not, I dont understand how to, well, get it back to the main thread.

EDIT:
Changed code to this...

```
public static void updatePermIconCache() {
    Logger.debug("thread1: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    hubDatabase.getLobbies().thenAccept(s -> {
        for (String lobby : s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
                final int x = i;
                hubDatabase.isInPermTable(lobby, i).thenAccept(b -> {
                    if (!b) return;
                    hubDatabase.cachePermToJoinTable(lobby, x).join();
                    registerPanels();
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is... main thread id is `21`, in the first line of the function `registerPanels()` I print the `Thread#currentThread#getId()` and it prints multiple different numbers, ranging between `30` and `42`. It should print `21` if it is ran on the main thread, right?

EDIT:
This is the first method that gets called that runs async

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> calibrate() {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        getLobbies().thenAccept(a -> Arrays.stream(a).forEach(this::createPermToJoinTable));
        getLobbies().thenAccept(a -> Arrays.stream(a).forEach(this::createVanishedTable));
    });
}

public CompletableFuture<String[]> getLobbies() {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM lobby";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    return queryAsync(r -> {
        while(r.next()) {
            list.add(r.getString(1));
        }
        return r;
    }, sql).thenApplyAsync(v -> list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
}
```

These methods are called initially from here...

```
public static CompletableFuture<Void> addToPerm(String lobby) {
    HubDatabase hubDatabase = MinelightHub.getHubDatabase();
    return hubDatabase.calibrate().thenRunAsync(() -> {
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 0, "Admin", getDesc(true), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.RED), Permissions.ADMIN, true);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 1, "Mod", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.ORANGE), Permissions.MOD, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 2, "Builder", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.CYAN), Permissions.BUILDER, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 3, "YouTube", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.RED), Permissions.YOUTUBE, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 9, "JrAdmin", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.RED), Permissions.JRADMIN, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 10, "JrMod", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.ORANGE), Permissions.JRMOD, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 11, "Artist", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.CYAN), Permissions.ARTIST, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 12, "Twitch", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.PURPLE), Permissions.TWITCH, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 17, "Default", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.GRAY), Permissions.DEFAULT, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 18, "SrMod", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.ORANGE), Permissions.SRMOD, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 19, "Trial", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.ORANGE), Permissions.TRIAL, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 20, "Partner", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.BLUE), Permissions.PARTNER, false);
        hubDatabase.addToPermToJoinTable(lobby, 21, "VIP", getDesc(false), Material.WOOL, getData(DyeColor.GREEN), Permissions.VIP, false);
    }).thenRunAsync(InventoryManager::updatePermIconCache);
}
```

Now you can kind of see the path that is necessary to help inform on this situation. 
When I create a 'lobby' the `#addToPerm(String lobby)` method gets run
Initially though, the tables in the SQL database need to be created before I can change add any data to it... This is what the (in the `#addToPerm(String lobby)` method) the `#calibrate` method does. Once it has created the lobbies I need to populate it with data, as such `hubDatabase#addToPermJoinTable()`. Once all that data is added, I then need to update my local cache, `InventoryManager#updatePermIconCache()`. Once all that cache is loaded, I then need to return to the main thread and call the `#registerPanels()` method as that method utilises a thread unsafe API. I am still stuck on how to do this...

Comment: Is the main thread doing something in the meantime? Or do you mean the GUI thread to make GUI calls from it?  In the latter case: Which GUI are you using (Swing, JavaFX)?

Comment: what is the difference between calling `registerPanels` in the main thread and in your `CompletableFuture` thread? and does `registerPanels` get called in your current setup when the db insert is completed?

Comment: `join()` will block the main thread until completablefuture is completes

Comment: Ok so that didnt seem to work...
Ive edited my main post

Comment: what do you mean by the main thread? that where the main() method runs? this is an ordinary thread, just the first thread.

Comment: Why do you want to run `registerPanels()` on the “main” thread? What is special about it? Good solutions will require this information to be relevant for you, otherwise it might be just pure guesses. It might also be good to provide a [mcve] to help better understand the problem.

Comment: BTW [`Thread.getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getName--) might be more interesting than `Thread.getId()` for debugging purposes. For instance you can immediately tell the main thread from its name.

Comment: registerPanels accesses an API that is reportedly thread unsafe, so Im trying to call it on the main thread so everything works smoothly

Comment: CompletableFuture are used for parallel programming. The scenario you described is sequential. Do it in ordinary way without CompletableFutures and be happy.

Comment: Then what happens if one of the SQL calls takes a while, that would block the main thread? I dont want that, I only want to call `registerPanels()` once everything is all completed, so that other stuff can continue working in the background until that happens.

Comment: What is the thread unsafe API behind `registerPanels()`? This looks like GUI stuff, and there aren't many GUI frameworks for Java out there… It most likely provides a way to do what you need out of the box.

Comment: The API is Spigot (Minecraft), the `registerPanels()` creates Minecraft [inventories](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/Inventory.html) and adds [ItemStack](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/inventory/ItemStack.html)'s to them.

Comment: I have never developed for Minecraft/Spigot but a quick goole for "CompletableFuture minecraft spigot" lead me to [_Sync -> Async -> Sync?_](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/sync-async-sync.260043/) and [TaskChain](https://github.com/aikar/TaskChain). Hope this helps. I also added the corresponding tags. This should give more visibility of your question to Minecraft developers, but you should also describe this is for Minecraft at the beginning of your question.

Comment: I dont want to use TaskChain, I want to do this with CompletableFuture's if possible, I would rather not depend on another library to complete this task, and all that thread that you linked does is suggest CompletableFuture's as well pretty much

Answer (score 0):

> Calling join() or get() only blocks the thread that the CompletableFuture is running in

So you are completing that future from the *current* thread? Don't do that then... ensure that all your async operations are performed, and their futures completed, on threads other than the thread you call `join` or `get` in.

Comment: So I have to go all through my web of async calls, and get the initial CompletableFuture and wait for that? I would much rather a simpler way >.>
Its a web of `thenAcceptAsync()'s` and `thenRunAsync()'s` etc... probably 20-30 different functions being called

Comment: You have to wait for the _final_ CompletableFuture - the one that depends on (is waiting for) all the others. Actually it doesn't have to wait for all the others, it can say "well, future A came back with a result so I don't care about future B any more because it's now irrelevant". But it is at the end of the tree of async calls. You can just put it in a variable or Map to keep track of it. You are right that you should not have to traverse the tree, but that's normally not necessary because we use variables.

Comment: I tried that, stuff doesnt work still... updating my post

Answer (score 0):

to return to a thread (main or not main, does not matter) that thread have to call some method which waits for given CompletableFuture. Waiting for CompletableFutureis done by calling its method  [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get--). That's it.

You are afraid that "Calling join() or get() only blocks the thread that the CompletableFuture is running in..." - this can only happen when join() or get() are called from a method called from CompletableFuture. Don't do this, the program would hang. Just start all your CompletableFutures. and only then call join() or get().

Since (as it is printed) method updatePermIconCache runs on different threads, this means it is not called from the main thread. We do not see what is called on the main thread and so we are unable to give you a proper advice.

Comment: I have updated my initial post explaining the process

Comment: @Realmm you still did not explain why you want  registerPanels() function to be called in the main thread. What do you mean by "main thread"? Is it GUI thread in Swing which is usually accessible by "SwingUtilities.invokeLater()"? Or do you use another kind of UI?

Comment: the main thread... the thread that the program runs on, and I did explain, see comments on the main post

Comment: @Realmm "the main thread... the thread that the program runs on" - this is a misconception. The program runs on each and every thread, not only on a main thread. " and I did explain, see comments on the main post" - no you did not. You did only one comment to the main post where main thread is mentioned: " API that is reportedly thread unsafe, so Im trying to call it on the main thread" which does not explain what the main thread is. Yes one of the ways to cope with thread unsafe API is access  it from a dedicated thread, but this thread hardly can be called main.

Comment: Then why, when you use Thread#sleep, does it halt the program, if the 'main thread' is spread over each and every thread? Either way, you know what I meant, Im just trying to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: @Realmm blocking (or making sleepeng) any important thread may block execution of the whole program, regardless of is it called main thread or not. And  'main thread' is not spread over each and every thread. There is no firm conception of what "main thread" is. Different people may think different about it. I am trying to understand what is your notion of main thread. Is it GUI thread? Is method registerPanels() a GUI method? If not, then you need not to execute that method on "main thread", but on some helper thread or better say, single threaded thread pool, or even "serial executor".

Comment: Refer to my latest comment on the main post to see what the method `registerPanels()` is about

Answer (score 0):

Call your service method where multithreading is being implemented from the main class. CompletableFuture's get() method will make sure that only after execution of all threads, it will return to the main method where the main thread is present and will get executed only after the return of get() method.

```
//Create a list of CompletableFutures:
List<CompletableFuture> futures= new ArrayList<>();

//Add your futures in this arrayList as mentioned below :
futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->{   
        // your code
});

CompletableFuture<Void> allCfs=CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));

try 
{
allCfs.get();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
} 

//Once this process will be completed, only then your main thread will get executed.

Main Thread()
```

Comment: add some line to explain how this code snippet helps

Comment: Call your service method where multithreading is being implemented from main class. CompletableFuture's get() method will make sure that only after execution of all threads, it will return to the main method where main thread is present and will get executed only after the return of get() method.

Comment: All threads are running separately and There are two kind of CompletableFutures. First is being used by all threads i.e. CompletableFuture.runAsync(() inside for loop and second is a list of all these thread's CompletableFuture. get() method is being called on this second CompletableFuture (which is a list).